# Add custom menu to drupal 7

Tags: drupal, themes

I have added a new menu to my drupal structure and I want to display this menu, under the main menu in my drupal theme.

I am not sure how to add a new menu and display it in my theme though?

I tried adding this to my page.tpl file:

```
<?php print theme('links', array('links' => menu_navigation_links('menu-download-categorys'), 'attributes' => array('class'=> array('links', 'downloads-menu')) ));?>
```

Comment: Sorry, I realised my mistake and this works fine. Had the wrong menu name.

Answer (score 0):

i use the following in drupal 7

```
<?php if (!empty($page['superfish_menu'])){ ?>
   <div id="superfish"><?php print  render($page['superfish_menu']); ?></div>
  <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, and particularly for a site you'll be handing off, is to manage your menus through the Drupal admin UI. You can add any Drupal Internal URL via the menu configuration UI: /admin/structure/menu/manage/main-menu for "Main Menu" and thus you wont have to fire up your ssh/file editor when you want to make further modifications to this menu.